# He [had] promised to help, but he [has] bailed out on us

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, past-simple

John promises Bob and Bill that he will help them, but then he simply doesn't turn up at the agreed time. Bob calls Peter (who cannot answer the call at the moment) and leaves him a voice message:

*1. Hi, Peter! Bill and I are at the warehouse. John **had promised** to help  us do some work here, but he'**s bailed** out on us. Please come and help us if you can. We're waiting for you.*

Peter listens to the voice message he's received and agrees to help Bob and Bill. He goes to the warehouse, and the three of them do the work that Bob and Bill have planned. At the end of the day, Bill bumps into Rick and tells him the whole story:

*2. Bob and I had to do some work at the warehouse today. We needed some help, so we asked John. He **promised** to help us, but then he **bailed** out on us, so we had to replace him with Peter.*

Do the bolded tenses work in examples #1 and #2 in their respective contexts? Thanks.

Comment: They work for me, although it would be simpler to say **John promised to help**.  The use of the past perfect suggests an implied extra clause - "John had promised to help [before he apparently changed his mind]."

Comment: @KateBunting Can I use the verb "run" in this context: "He promised to help us, but then he ran out on us."?

Comment: I think *ran out on* would work (I'd certainly understand it), but that phrase is usually used in the context of relationships/families.

Comment: To get more useful answers, please edit the question to tell more about *why* you have doubts. These are good uses of these tenses, but if there's some confusion about them, explaining it can be more useful than just saying "yes, they're ok."

Comment: I've often heard **bailed** used without the following **out**, thus *but then he bailed on us* meaning exactly the same thing.